# ASP.NET unhandled errors in application log - how to disable?

Tags: iis, asp.net

As the title says - how do I disable all of the ASP.NET unhandled errors appearing in the event log? Cant see anything obvious in IIS / the web.config...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of right now is through a code-based solution, not web.config. In the global.asax file for your application, you can add an Application_Error event handler. In this, you can do whatever you want to do to log the error (or not...) and then redirect to an appropriate error page. Call `Context.ClearError()` before redirecting, and none of the standard ASP.Net unhandled excpetion stuff will kick in. This is not a pretty way to handle this though, so hopefully somebody else has a better answer.

A simple global.asax that does only this functionality would look like:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
<script runat="server">
protected void Application_Error(object src, EventArgs e)
{
  Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
  // do whatever you want to the error itself (ex.Message, etc.)
  // ####
  // clear out the ASP.Net error
  Context.ClearError();
  // redirect to an error page
  Response.Redirect("errorpage.aspx");

}
</script>
```

With all that being said, there has to be a way to do this using the web.config healthMonitoring section, I just can't figure out how to say "turn off logging for all events".